# Boost ASIO async_write_some is really slow

Tags: c++, networking, boost, boost-asio

I finally found the bottleneck of my server and it turns out to be `async_write` and the same goes for `async_write_some`.

Here the following benchmark code:

```
struct timespec start, end;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);

//boost::asio::async_write(mMainData.mSocket, boost::asio::buffer(pSendBuff->pBuffer, pSendBuff->dwUsedSize), mMainData.mStrand.wrap(boost::bind(&CServer::WriteHandler, pServer, this, pSendBuff, boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred)));
mMainData.mSocket.async_write_some(boost::asio::buffer(pSendBuff->pBuffer, pSendBuff->dwUsedSize), (boost::bind(&CServer::WriteHandler, pServer, this, pSendBuff, boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred)));

clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);

timespec temp;
if ((end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) < 0)
{
    temp.tv_sec = end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec - 1;
    temp.tv_nsec = 1000000000 + end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec;
}
else
{
    temp.tv_sec = end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec;
    temp.tv_nsec = end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec;
}

pLogger->WriteToFile("./Logs/Benchmark_SendPacketP_AsyncWrite.txt", "dwDiff: %.4f\r\n", (float)temp.tv_nsec / 1000000.0f);
```

And the output:

```
-[2016.05.21 03:45:19] dwDiff: 0.0552ms
-[2016.05.21 03:45:19] dwDiff: 0.0404ms
-[2016.05.21 03:45:19] dwDiff: 0.0542ms
-[2016.05.21 03:45:20] dwDiff: 0.0576ms
```

This is absurdly slow as it is a gameserver and i need to broadcast packets in room channels, which have 300 players in 1 channel, imagine the network delay it causes to my players.

Ofcourse this test was done with only myself in the server.

Is it my code that is wrong or am i missing something in ASIO implementation logic?

```
CXXFLAGS: -ggdb -ffunction-sections -Ofast -m64 -pthread -fpermissive -w -lboost_system -lboost_thread -Wall -fomit-frame-pointer
LDFLAGS: -Wl,-gc-sections -m64 -pthread -fpermissive -w -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lcurl
```

The hardware is:
Intel Xeon E3-1231v3 (4 cores, 8 threads)
64GB RAM
1GBPS Uplink

I am spawning 8 ASIO workers.

So i was stepping inside the async_write with a debugger and found this:

```
template <typename ConstBufferSequence, typename Handler>
void async_send(base_implementation_type& impl,
  const ConstBufferSequence& buffers,
  socket_base::message_flags flags, Handler& handler)
{
bool is_continuation =
  boost_asio_handler_cont_helpers::is_continuation(handler);

// Allocate and construct an operation to wrap the handler.
typedef reactive_socket_send_op<ConstBufferSequence, Handler> op;
typename op::ptr p = { boost::asio::detail::addressof(handler),
  boost_asio_handler_alloc_helpers::allocate(
    sizeof(op), handler), 0 };
p.p = new (p.v) op(impl.socket_, buffers, flags, handler);

BOOST_ASIO_HANDLER_CREATION((p.p, "socket", &impl, "async_send"));

start_op(impl, reactor::write_op, p.p, is_continuation, true,
    ((impl.state_ & socket_ops::stream_oriented)
      && buffer_sequence_adapter<boost::asio::const_buffer,
        ConstBufferSequence>::all_empty(buffers)));
p.v = p.p = 0;
}
```

Why would boost::asio call "new" in a supposed to be high performance library?
Is there anyway to precreate what its trying to allocate?
Sorry i cannot profile the internals as im developing with VisualGDB with Microsoft Visual Studio, with having the GCC 4.8.5 toolset running in VMWare.

Comment: You will need to show more of your code. It's more likely there's a problem in the way you're handing this, rather than performance of `booost::asio`.  300 clients is a relatively tiny number.

Comment: Which code do you want? i showed where exactly is the bottleneck, exactly between the timing check code, which is async_write, and by the documentations, async_write should return immediately as it is an async operation, not a blocking one, so obviously it isnt my code unless you can tell me something that i dont know.

Comment: I think you missed a detail as i said i need to broadcast the channels status, which means i need to send a channel update packet to all the 300 players at once, frequently.

Comment: And if you add up 0.0576ms per async_write, multiplied by 300 players, you get a 17.28ms ping increase, so it can be even 100 players, it can be any "tiny" amount of players, that is still an unacceptable blocking delay for any decent server. And please notice that i am measuring the call async_write itself till it returns, not till it call my write_handler, it shouldn't be blocking!

Comment: As a solution you can submit items into a queue and use io_service:post() to trigger a sequence of write operations. post() should return faster than async_write_some()

Comment: A [mcve] or a profiler would be helpful in attributing the performance.  Can you duplicate the same results with something like this [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/18bc1905d1aa680b)?  Also, why not parallelize the broadcast?

Comment: alexm, this is going to returns faster but wont the endresult be the same afterall since io_service will end up calling async_write at some point right?

Comment: Does by any chance can boost::bind cause parts of this overhead and if yes can i pre-create a handler function per client?

Comment: I have added more details to the question, i have stepped into async_write using gdb and found out that its calling new as every async_send call.

Comment: If I understand the placement new correctly it's not allocating something here - it's simply calling the constructor and placing the result in `p.v`. [Read more about placement new here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new). Are you sure that it's that instruction which is the bottleneck?

Comment: Nop, that i cant profile since im using VisualGDB, very sorry. I tought this could be the bottleneck. Also the question in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893200/does-boostasio-makes-excessive-small-heap-allocations-or-am-i-wrong is solving the handler allocation, i have implemented it and it even increased to 0.1101ms after the implementation, this is crazy i have no idea whats going on anymore, i am even thinking of switching libraries.

Comment: Regarding the use of operator new, your code quotes *placement* new which does not allocate memory. However ASIO does allocate and deallocate memory per i/o, it's architecturally hard to not do this with how Windows IOCP is designed, but you *can* replace the allocator used by ASIO for these allocations to simply return some blocks held on a linked list. But in the end ASIO is merely quite high performance, not VERY high performance, and its design is based on how systems worked 15 years ago, not modern OSs which have come a very long way since.

Comment: For example, on Windows if you want truly superb network i/o performance, look into Windows RIO (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh997032(v=ws.11).aspx). This lets you concurrently send as many as 1024 UDP packets at once. That OS API really lets you exercise 100 Gbit network cards, but it demands a totally different (and usually proprietary) architecture from your software.

Comment: Really good idea, however im using TCP for rooms lobby and UDP for gameplay. Currently im focusing on improving TCP issues.

Comment: Niall Douglas, which library do you recommend that is more modern and faster than ASIO? My OS is currently CentOS 7 x64.

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer is a bit late but I am posting it in case someone finds this useful.

Indeed there is a call to new when a completion handler is posted. However, official documentation explains how to optimize so as to avoid related runtime overhead by implementing custom memory management. Here is the example:
[custom memory management for completion handlers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/allocation/server.cpp)

Answer (score 0):

Without a profiler, trying to identify which instruction is the bottleneck will likely be a futile test of patience.  Creating a minimal example may help identify the source of the problem in a particular environment.  For example, in a controlled scenario where there is neither contention for the I/O nor the `io_service`, I observe 0.015ms~ writes for when using [native `write()`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3bc0777a137fb65a) and [Asio's `async_write()`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/18bc1905d1aa680b).

The problem attempting to be solved is to write the same message to 300 peers with minimal latency.  One solution may be to parallelize the problem: instead of having a single job that writes the message to 300 peers serially, consider using `n` jobs that run in parallel and write the message to `300/n` peers serially.  With some rough estimates:

- if 300 writes are performed serially, with each taking .015ms (observed average when using native `write()` in a controlled environment), the final write will start 4.485ms after the first write.
- if 300 writes are batched based on the potential concurrency limit (8 in this example), there will be 8 jobs running in parallel performing 38 writes serially.  If each write takes the 0.0576ms (observed on actual system), the final write will start 2.13ms after the first write.

With the above estimates, by paralleling the problem, its takes half the time to write to 300 peers, even when each individual `asyc_write` operation takes longer than expected.  Keep in mind that these are rough estimates, and one would need to profile to determine the ideal amount of concurrency, as well as identify the underlying bottlenecks.

Comment: Thanks alot for a contribution. As you said, i could also get the same delay with calling the native write, could this be possible that it is linux specific? And if its the case, its possible that Windows may have a different delay? Cause if yes i am gonna get a dedi windows server and run tests.

Comment: @NoobyLearner I poorly expressed my point.  In the answer, I link to examples that demonstrate both the native `write()` and Asio's `async_write()` taking 0.015ms~.  Can you reproduce the 0.05ms delays in a [mcve]?  If you want to identify instructions that are bottlenecks, use a profiler.  However, I suspect that changing the algorithm would yield better results.

Comment: In the time being, i have distributed the async_write between all the ASIO threads. Also, instead of sending multiple update packets per player, i have copied all the packets into one buffer and sending it in one async_write call. However, sometimes i cannot copy all the packets into one single packet due to design, so i am inserting all the buffers into a "vector<boost::asio::const_buffer>" and sending all of them into one async_write call. So far this has increased the performance, however i still want to minimize the delay.

Comment: Tanner, by your tests you got a 0.015ms delay by calling the native write(), is there some custom configuration that could be done to linux sysctl for improving this delay? I am thinking that if ASIO got notified that the socket is ready to write, the write call should be ultra fast.